# Masstransit, return the consumed message

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm kind of new to Masstransit and I'm not exactly sure how to configure this.
Is there a way to return the consumed message back to where I call the Consume method?
The Consume method returns IBusControl but I can't get hold of the message.

The actual Consume method is somehow called through the ReceiveEndpoint, and this Consume method returns a Task whoch holds the message. So my question is, how to get this message back to the ConsumeMessage method so that I can populate the InventoryItemObject with the result.

```
public IInventory ConsumeMessage(string domainId)
    {
        using (consumer = new MassTransitConsumer(MassTransitConsumer.GetConfiguration()))
        {
            try
            {
                var message = consumer.Consume(domainId).StartAsync().Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return new InventoryItemObject();
    }

        public IBusControl Consume(string queue)
    {

        var endpoint = new Uri(string.Concat(configuration.HostAddress, "/", queue));

        try
        {
            if (configuration.QueueType == "RabbitMQ" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuration.QueueType))
            {
                bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rabbit =>
                {
                    IRabbitMqHost host = rabbit.Host(configuration.HostAddress, settings =>
                    {
                        settings.Username(configuration.Username);
                        settings.Password(configuration.Password);
                    });

                    rabbit.ReceiveEndpoint(host, queue, c =>
                    {
                        c.UseConcurrencyLimit(1);
                        c.UseRetry(retryConfig => retryConfig.Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
                        c.Consumer(() => new InventoryConsumer(_connectionString));
                    });
                });

                bus.Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }

        return bus;
    }

public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IInventory> context)
    {
        var inventory = context.Message;

        _logger.LogDebug($"Order object: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inventory, Formatting.Indented)}");
        _logger.LogDebug("Stating timer for UserChangeEventConsumer:");

        var timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        var message = context.Message;

        SetMessageAsConsumed(message);

        timer.Stop();
        _logger.LogDebug($"UserChangeEventConsumer completed in {timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds.");

        return Task.FromResult(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you want to return the message? As far as I know, it's best practice to simply not have the Consume method return the message, because there shouldn't be anyone there to listen.

If you want to return something to the publisher, you should use the [request/response pattern](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html#request-consumer)

Comment: My client wants me to convert all messages consumed to specific objects that will be returned in Swagger. When they are consumed they're gone and there's no other way to get them.

Comment: Perhaps you could use Middleware to intercept the message? https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "returned in Swagger".